# Why list comprehetion deletes a int?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have written a piece of code that unpacks a struct with this format:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 unsigned char | 7 char | 13 char | 7 char | 50 char |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

So when I execute this code:

```
datagram = unpack('1B7s13s7s50s',raw_datagram[0])
print len(datagram)
datagram = [data.replace('\x00','') for data in list(datagram) if isinstance(data, str)]
print len(datagram)
```

The *output* is:

```
5  
4
```

And the `raw_datagram[0]` is:

> (0, 'SW-01\x00\x00', '89F107457A36\x00', '000000\x00', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')

Why did it delete the first integer?

Comment: Because you filtered the list comprehension on strings.

Comment: I removed your second question, please focus your questions on a single issue at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filtered your output list on strings only, because you include a `if ...` test in your list comprehension:

```
[data.replace('\x00','') for data in list(datagram) if isinstance(data, str)]
#                        all entries in datagram,   that are strings
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_datagram = []
for data in list(datagram):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        new_value = data.replace('\x00','')
        new_datagram.append(new_value)
datagram = new_datagram
```

You want to use a *conditional expression* instead:

```
new_datagram = []
for data in datagram:
    new_value = data.replace('\x00','') if isinstance(data, str) else data
    new_datagram.append(new_value)
datagram = new_datagram
```

or, as a list comprehension:

```
datagram = [data.replace('\x00','') if isinstance(data, str) else data for data in datagram]
```

I'd use `str.rstrip('\x00')` here, as the null bytes are probably only used as length padding:

```
datagram = [data.rstrip('\x00') if isinstance(data, str) else data for data in datagram]
```

and because you know the format already, you only need to apply this to the 4 elements that are strings:

```
datagram = [datagram[0]] + [data.rstrip('\x00') for data in datagram[1:]]
```